OPE limit of four-point function in de Sitter space
I have been trying to read the paper 'Cosmological Collider Physics'. This paper studies several things, of
which the most interesting to me was studying the correlation function in de Sitter space by solving the conformal
Ward identity. I understood how to derive the four-point function for a scalar field by solving CWI, but I don't
understand how we do the same for tensor fields. I am particularly stuck at how the authors derived the four-point
function with a spinning particle intermediate state as given by equation (5.105) in subsection 5.3.1. In this
section, we are studying the OPE limit of the four-point function for an interaction of the form $(\nabla \xi)^2
\sigma$, where $\xi$ is a conformally coupled scalar and $\sigma$ is a tensor field.
$$I_{+-} = \sum_m \langle O_2 O_2 O_{\Delta, m} \rangle' \frac{1}{k_I^{2\Delta - 3} I_2(\Delta, m)} \langle
O_{\Delta, -m} O_2 O_2 \rangle'.$$
The same result is also used in section 6.2 with the only difference being that we sandwich the inverse of a
two-point function between three-point functions and two-point functions.
$$I_{+-} = \left\langle O_3 O_3 O_{\Delta, m=0} \right\rangle' \frac{1}{k_I^{2\Delta - 3} I_2(0)} \left\langle
O_{\Delta, m=0} O_3 \right\rangle'_{\text{Inf}}.$$
Any help or hint would be very appreciated.
